# Convert military time to standard time with am pm (without seconds) using DateFormat formatter wherein the time is from JSONOBject

Tags: java, php, eclipse

Eclipse:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String formatstart_time=json_data.getString("start_time");
String formatend_time=json_data.getString("end_time");

                try {

                        Time startValue = new Time(formatter.parse(formatstart_time).getTime());
                        Time endValue = new Time(formatter.parse(formatend_time).getTime());
                        user.setStartTime(startValue);//error
                        user.setEndTime(endValue);//error
                        //if string contains su and myday is sunday bla bla
                        user.setDay(parseDay(json_data.getString("day")));
                        mysched.add(user);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT course_id, sections_id, rooms_id, start_time, end_time, day, studsched.schedule_id from schedule_tbl as sched,student_schedule_tbl as studsched where sched.schedule_id=studsched.schedule_id and student_id='$id' GROUP BY course_id, sections_id,sched_status='active';";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $json_output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json_output);
```

I have my time in my table, the column is start_time and end_time.

Sample table column data:

```
start_time=11:30:00 
end_time=16:00:00.
```

I am doing the query in my php, and then im getting the values through web service in eclipse. I want the data as (based from above) 11:30 AM - 4:00 PM, the military time will be converted to standard time and then without the second. Can you help me convert it using DateFormat formatter?

Answer (score 0):

You parse the date with `DateTime::createFromFormat` and then format it according to your needs… just like you'd do with any other date as well:

```
$start_time = "11:30:00";
$end_time = "16:00:00";

$start = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat("H:i:s", $start_time);
$end = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat("H:i:s", $end_time);

echo $start->format("g:i A") .  " - " . $end->format("g:i A"), PHP_EOL;
```

This will print

```
11:30 AM - 4:00 PM
```

Please refer to the available formatting options at http://php.net/date

Comment: thank you for your comment however my start and end time is not predefined :(

Comment: i wish to convert it inside my eclipse, because the data inside my php is getting another values aside from the time and echoing it through json_encode

Comment: @picolo why dont you just format it the way you want it when you retrieve it?